# How would I go about connecting to a network drive from a VPN using Cisco AnyConnect?

Tags: wireless, networking, vpn, drive

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and am pretty new to it all but in order to continue using Ubuntu I absolutely have to be able to connect to this network drive for my work. When I am using windows 7 it allowed me to connect and then map the drive permanently as a network drive. Any ideas?

Some additional info. I am able to connect to the VPN completely fine. However once I connect, I don't really see a way to add the network drive. I know that there is a connect to network option but I messed around with that and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba) on your Ubuntu server.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into in now. Asked this question literally 6 times in different forums and message boards but nobody would help.